# soylent, ensure, boost and FODMAP

Tags: nutrition, diet

Sometimes I eat [soylent](https://www.soylent.com/), [ensure](https://ensure.com/) or [boost](https://www.boost.com/), but now I decided follows the [low FODMAP](http://shepherdworks.com.au/disease-information/low-fodmap-diet) diet.

Do above products belong to low or high FODMAP?

According to [this discussion](https://discourse.soylent.com/t/soylent-ibs-the-low-fodmap-diet-and-gut-bacteria/11463/) soylent is okay, but I'm not sure about ensure and boost.